# How do I open a directory with Windows File Explorer through the Ubuntu Linux Terminal Subsystem?

Tags: directory, windows-10, filemanager

I simply want to see my folder pop up in Windows File Explorer using a command like:

```
open ./
```

I've seen examples like:

```
nautilus ./
xdg-open ./
```

But I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS inside of Microsoft Windows 10 and I don't think Nautilus or XDG file manager GUI's work on Windows 10. I got this error message:

```
$ nautilus ex00/
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(nautilus:17): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:51:09.385: cannot open display:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By explorer nicholas' answer we could use this:

```bsh
$ ~/some/dir explorer.exe .
```

and by alias `explorer.exe` we can use `open` just like Linux with GUI:

```bsh
# ~/.bash_rc or ~/.zshrc
alias open="explorer.exe"
```

and now you can open subsystem folder with

```bsh
$ ~/some/dir open .
$ ~/some/dir open /usr/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

So I did some research and found that that Nautilus and XDG certainly does not work on Windows 10 OS, and upon further investigation, found that the Ubuntu root folder and anything beyond that directory should NEVER be open in Windows File Explorer or any other Windows apps or tools for that matter. The data will be corrupted due to different metadata file structure or something like that.

However, upon even deeper research, I found this article:

[WSL Update Lets You Access Linux Files in Windows Explorer](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/02/access-linux-files-from-windows-explorer-wsl)